# Console App Errors If it can't find a certain file to rename

Tags: c#

I found this code that can change a file on ya desktop but if the file is not named correct you can't open the Console App because of a error.

```cs
System.IO.File.Move("youarenotgay.txt", "youarenowgay.txt");
```

Comment: What is the expected outcome you want? You can set watchers on the filesystem to see if files are locked or moved before you do what you want to do. Are you wanting the console app to not crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for the file's existence like this:

```
if(System.IO.File.Exists("myfilename.txt")
{
    System.IO.File.Move("myfilename.txt", "myfilenamenew.txt");
}
```

That way you can react to the file not existing or being named different and avoid the exception.